# How do I stop userform button.initialize value change running button.click()

Tags: excel, vba

I want to pull through an initial value/state to a button upon initializing a userform.

The issue I am having is that when it goes to the:

```
"If setupws.Cells(question1row, currentsetupcol).Value = "1" Then
 Question1Button.Value = True"
```

It then jumps into the Question1Button_Click() sub.

How do I get it to pull through the initial setup state without jumping into the click sub?

I want the click sub to be for clicking only and not the initial setup of the userform.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim buildphasews As Worksheet
    Dim Leadprogws As Worksheet
    Dim inputWks As Worksheet
    Dim setupws As Worksheet

Set setupws = Worksheets("13 Table - BuildPhase Applic")
currentsetupcol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Current Sheet 
Setup", setupws.Range("A1:AZ1"), 0)

  If setupws.Cells(question1row, currentsetupcol).Value = "1" Then
  Question1Button.Value = True
  Question1Button.Caption = "question 1 will be asked"
  MsgBox "will"
  Else
  Question1Button.Value = False
  Question1Button.Caption = "question 1 will not be asked"
  MsgBox "not"
  End If

 End Sub

 Private Sub Question1Button_Click() 

Select Case Question1Button.Value
    Case True
          'MsgBox "true"
        Question1Button.Caption = "Question 1 will be asked"

    Case False
        'MsgBox "false"
           Question1Button.Caption = "Question 1 will not be asked"

    End Select
 'Call PreviousSetup
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm presuming all you want to do is enable the button? If so, try this: `Question1Button.Enable = True`

Comment: Or load a `Boolean` variable either `True`or `False` and put it in the optionbutton click event. `If BlnVar = False then Exit Sub`...something like that. [Here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SuppressChangeInForms.htm) is some information on that.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `Value` of a button simulates physically clicking the button. If I remember correctly the `_Click()` event is raised after the button's `Value` is set to `False` again, so your solution of checking the button value cannot work.

Try using the [Checkbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/checkbox-control).

However if you want to use only the button you need a Boolean; something like this:

```
' In your Userform Code
Option Explicit
Dim someBool as Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    [...]
    ' Instead of Question1Button.Value = True you do
    someBool = True
    [...]
    ' And instead of Question1Button.Value = False you do
    Somebool = False
    [...]
End Sub

Private Sub Question1Button_Click() 
     Select Case SomeBool
     Case True
         Question1Button.Caption = "Question 1 will be asked"
     Case False
         Question1Button.Caption = "Question 1 will not be asked"
     End Select
     'Call PreviousSetup
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the application.enableevents function. I put =false in the intialize sub and the below in the button_click sub.

```
Private Sub Question1Button_Click()
If Application.EnableEvents = False Then
Exit Sub
Else

Select Case Question1Button.Value
Case True
    'MsgBox "true"
    Question1Button.Caption = "Question 1 will be asked"
Case False
    'MsgBox "false"
    Question1Button.Caption = "Question 1 will not be asked"
End Select
End If
```

It now does everything I need.

Thank you for the answer anyway.

Comment: That's really not the best solution. What happens when you unload the userform? Where do you set `Application.Enableevents = True`?

Comment: How is that even supposed to be doing what you asked in your question? Your If clause will be `True` if you put `Application.EnableEvents = False` in the `UserForm_Initialize()` and thus your program exits the sub.

Comment: This in effect fully disables the click function, but will still modify whether the button is a true or false. I then use the true or false value later to change the setup sheet value through a different button.